# Ayuda con reloj digital, precionando boton para cambiar el modo fecha a alarma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Me gustaría saber si alguien me podría ayudar con este reloj digital, el cual consiste en lo siguiente: al presionar un botón el pasaría a modo alarma, el cual se mostraría **H,M,S**, con otro botón configurar la **H,M,S**(un click aceptar,doble click pasar al siguiente), otro botón para aceptar la configuración, y el ultimo es para detener la alarma. Estoy usando `HTML`, `CSS`, `JS` y `JQuery`.

Adjunto código del reloj.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Reloj Digital</title>
    <link
        href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Russo+One|Exo+2:100|Codystar|Emilys+Candy|Jolly+Lodger|Nova+Square'
        rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
</head>

<body onLoad="startTime()">
    <div id="container-flex">

        <div id="eventos">
            <h2>Funciones del reloj</h2>
            <button id="btn_crono_reloj" onclick="btn1()">Modo reloj/cronometro</button><br><br>
            <button id="btn_luz" onclick="btn2()">Modo activar luz</button><br><br>
            <button id="btn_alarma" onclick="btn3()">Modo alarma</button><br><br>
            <button id="btn_fecha" onclick="btn4()">Modo fecha</button><br><br>

        </div>

        <div id="relojdigital">
            <div class="t_correa"></div>
            <div class="b_correa"></div>
            <div class="l_caja"></div>
            <div class="m_caja"></div>
            <div class="r_caja"></div>
            <button class="l_boton1" id="btn1" onclick="btn1()"></button>
            <button class="r_boton2" id="btn2" onclick="btn2()"></button>
            <button class="r_boton3" id="btn3" onclick="btn3()"></button>
            <button class="l_boton4" id="btn4" onclick="btn4()"></button>
            <div class="pantalla" id="led">
                <div class="segundero">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <script src="js/boton1.js"></script>
        <script src="js/boton2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/boton3.js"></script>
        <script src="js/boton4.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Mi `JS`, el cual solo activado el modo luz.

`JS`

```
function btn2() {

    if (document.getElementById('btn2').innerHTML == '.') {

        document.getElementById('btn2').innerHTML = '';
        document.getElementById('btn2').style.backgroundColor = 'black';
    } else {

        document.getElementById('btn2').innerHTML = '.';
        document.getElementById('btn2').style.backgroundColor = '#cdcdcd';

    }
}

$('.r_boton2').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.pantalla').toggleClass("light");
});
```

El `CSS` no lo coloco ya que esta bastante largo, pero si alguien lo necesita para un mayor entendimiento lo coloco, no hay problema.

Comment: Hola @BernalHD, no entiendo cual es exactamente tu pregunta. ¿Qué es lo que te está dando error o en lo que estás atascado? Sabiendo cual es el problema exacto sería mucho más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: @FranciscoRomero, es un reloj digital, en la pantalla se muestra lo normal de un reloj, pero cuando yo presione un boton, la pantalla cambiara a otro modo, en este caso modo alarma, estando en el modo alarma, ya podria establecer la alarma, pero el cambio de pantalla es lo que no se como hacerlo.